# Select column based on the value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table structure like this:

```
FIELD         | VALUE
--------------+----------
COLUMN_NAME_A | VALUE_1
COLUMN_NAME_B | VALUE_2
```

The value of the `FIELD` column is the name of a column in another table. I need to somehow select values from this table that exist within the column listed on the other table, and I can't just hard code it because it could change at any time without notice.

Is there a way to select a column based off the value in a column on a separate table?

So I essentially need something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM other_table 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME_A = VALUE_1
```

Comment: Do `other_table` and `your-column-nam-A table` have any relationships on any fields?

Comment: no, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

```
  create procedure Proc_name as 
       DECLARE @myCursor cursor;
       DECLARE @sqlSelect   char(400);
       DECLARE   @value char(100);
  BEGIN
      SET @myCursor = CURSOR FOR
         SELECT field from source_table 
     OPEN @myCursor
  FETCH NEXT FROM @myCursor
      INTO @value

     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
          SET @sqlSelect  =  ' select * from  Other_table where 
      COLUMN_NAME_A =' + @value  
          EXEC (@sqlSelect)
                      FETCH NEXT FROM @myCursor INTO  @value
    END   
       CLOSE @myCursor
    DEALLOCATE @myCursor

   END
```

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted. It is the correct (ugly) solution to the (ugly) question answered. The only better answer, would conceivably be "Don't", which whilst probably true, sounds unlikely to be useful to the asker here - this sounds like an inherritted legacy system to me.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll look into it. Unfortunately this is data I don't have control over and must work within those limitations, otherwise I'm sure there's a better way to structure it.